# Glue two user defined vars together in trigger

Tags: mysql

Pretty basic, I presume, but not today :-) It's driving me nuts. How to glue two user defined vars together in a trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_table2 AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      SET @var1="A";
      SET @var2="B";
      SET @varT="";
        ????? 
      UPDATE table2 SET val=@varT;
      END
```

I like varT to be 'AB'

I've tried

```
@varT=CONCAT(@var1,@var2);
@varT=@var1+@var2;
@varT=@var1.@var2;
```

but none of them works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET @t = CONCAT(@a, @b);
```

or

```
SELECT CONCAT(@a, @b) INTO @t;
```

or

```
SELECT @t := CONCAT(@a, @b);
```

But I'd rather

```
UPDATE table2 SET val = CONCAT(@a, @b);
```

Comment: You're first solution did the trick. Even when declared earlier, it only works when you declare the variable again. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

**solved**

the right syntax is

```
SET @varT=CONCAT(@var1,@var2);
```

even if you want to add multiple strings, the SET seems to be required.

```
SET @var1='A';
SET @var2='B';
SET @var3='C';
SET @XXX = CONCAT(@var1,@var2);
SET @XXX = CONCAT(@XXX,@var3);
```

results in 'ABC';

Comment: FYI: [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) accepts more than 2 arguments. `SET @XXX = CONCAT(@var1, @var2, @var3);`

Comment: You are right. This was a very simplified version of what I am up to, only to figure out how to glue the strings together. But thnx!

Comment: `SET` does not "declare" a variable, it "sets" its value. You do not really declare user variables in (My)SQL (somewhat similar to PHP: `SELECT @whatever_label_never_used_before` always returns `NULL`).